# cli php.ini and web phpinfo() not pointed

Tags: linux, centos, php, php7

li php.ini and web phpinfo() not pointed

After setting up LAMP in centos I tried

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

But on web

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>

Loaded Configuration File (none)
```

my web shows openssl is enabled but php cli shows its disabled.

[image]

Comment: You are missing configuring your server. You are the administrator of the server, you are supposed to administer it. In the specific case of the question, you are supposed to provide initialization files for the various PHP SAPIs. You must understand how the web server runs PHP in order to execute that `phpinfo()` call; you are supposed to examine the configuration files for the selected mechanism, and edit them according to the specific situation.

Comment: The CLI and web are using two different `php.ini` files (`/usr/local/lib/php.ini` vs `/usr/local/php7/lib/php.ini`), and quite possible different versions of `php` as well.

Comment: But there is no php.ini file in /usr/local/php7/lib/ if I add them how do I point to appache to use /usr/local/php7/lib/ instead of /usr/local/lib

Comment: created a php.ini to /usr/local/php7/lib/ it pointed to web phpinfo(), How do I tell CLI to point to /usr/local/php7/lib/php.ini

Comment: I this I got it wrongly, Does it work by pointing, What do I need to do.

Comment: it points to PHP7 when I do /usr/local/php7/bin/php -m how do I avoid this long step, Whats the real fix.

Answer (score 0):

I started to use what I have in my PHP.ini file

I have installed two Version of php one to the **default** path and other to **/usr/local/php7/bin/php**

Since I am using Magento I cant run setup:upgrade with

> /php bin/magento setup:upgrade

I just pointed it to config path which I have in my php.ini

> /usr/local/php7/bin/php bin/magento setup:upgrade